# Are there any exorcisms in the Old Testament?

Tags: old-testament, demons, exorcism, demon-possession

In the New Testament Jesus performs an exorcism (Mark 1:23–26, Luke 11:14–26) and Jesus gave that authority over to the apostles themselves to drive out evil spirits and to perform exorcisms (Matthew 10:1), but did any of the prophets from the Old Testament perform exorcisms?

Answer (score 0):

**Are there any exorcisms in the Old Testament?**

There seem to be at least two allusions to exorcisms in the Old Testament.

> The first allusion to exorcism appears in the Bible, in the youth narratives of David (1 Samuel). But while the biblical David seemed to be able to effect a temporary expulsion of Saul’s evil spirit using music, the book of Tobit contains the first explicit description of an (informal) exorcism.  Josephus recounts incidents of possession and exorcism in his Antiquities of the Jews (2, 5, 8, 45-48). In his description, exorcism involved burning herbs and immersing the possessed person in water. The New Testament also reports Jesus to have performed numerous exorcisms of demonic spirits in first-century Palestine (Matthew 12; Mark 5, 6, 13; Luke 8).
>
> The Dead Sea Scrolls include several exorcism incantations and formulae, mostly directed against disease-causing demons. The DSS Psalms collection in particular (11Q5) has “four songs for the charming of demons with music.” People who fell under the influence of false prophets and mediums were thought to also require the exorcism of possessing evil spirits (the false prophets and mediums themselves were subject to death, a sure cure for most possessions; see Zechariah 13). - [Jewish Exorcism](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/jewish-exorcism/)

Although the [Book of Tobit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Tobit) is not in the Protestant Bible, it is recognized as canonical in both the Catholic and Orthodox Bibles.

Comment: Demons would be more likely to gather at the smell of rotten fish than to flee from it.  Consider Matthew 24:28.

Comment: @Biblasia Demons being of the spiritual world and not of the physical world can not smell!

Answer (score 0):

The word "exorcism" is not used in the OT, but something close to it is described in David's driving away the evil spirit that God had sent to King Saul.

> Whenever the evil spirit from God came upon Saul, David took the lyre
> and played it with his hand, and Saul would be relieved and feel
> better, and the evil spirit would depart from him. (1 Sam. 16:23)

Also, in the Book of Tobit (OT Apocrypha) the angel Raphael instructs Tobit's son Tobias in a special technique to perform an exorcism to liberate Tobias' bride Sarah from a powerful demon, Ashmodai, who had killed her previous seven husbands:

> Tobias remembered the words of Raphael, and he took the fish’s liver
> and heart out of the bag where he had them and put them on the embers
> of the incense.  The odor of the fish so repelled the demon that he
> fled to the remotest parts of Egypt. (Tobit 8:2-3)

These are the only two known cases in the OT and its Apocrypha in which an exorcism is described.

Comment: Demons would no more be repelled by the odor of fish than would mosquitoes be repelled by the application of sugar water to one's skin.  The apocryphal reference sounds more like an attempt at humor than actual realism.  There's a reason it was not accepted into the canon, and is classed as pseudepigrapha.

Comment: I agree that demons would not be repelled by the odor of fish but not that this is an attempt at humor. Regarding canonicity, the Book of Tobit is accepted as part of the Orthodox and Catholic canon. It is part of the OT Apocrypha. Technically it cannot be classed  as [pseudepigrapha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_apocrypha#Pseudepigrapha) because it author is anonymous.